# How to prevent component re-rendering with history.push in react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component like shown below

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({history}) => {
  const {data,loading,error} = someExpensiveQuery({...});
  return(
    <Switch>
     <Route path='/somePath'>
     // A huge list of all items in expensive query onClick = history.push('path to below component')
     <Route path='somePath/edit/27523'>
    // A component to edit ONE of the items in the big list
    </Switch>
)}
```

The component renders a huge list and upon clicking on any item in the list, renders the component to edit *one* of those items.
The paths are like '/somePath' and '/somePath/edit/:id'.
My problem is that I want to not cause the entire component to re-render and query the big list everytime I click on an item and go back but it seems to do exactly that(because history itself is a prop). How do I get past this problem ?

Comment: I think you want to use useMemo from react hooks

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I suggest you use `useMemo()` hook.

Wrap your state (your query) in `useMemo()`, and only when you actually edit an item, React will re-render the whole page.

Or you can save the state in the parent component instead of executing the the query every time a child component renders so that only reloading the page does so.